# What's the purpose of the -g flag in "npm install" commands?

Tags: command-line, apt, npm

I am a beginner to Linux. I am using 14.04 Ubuntu. When I tried to install node I found a `-g` flag which says that if you install with it, it can be accessed globally.

So I tried to install nodejs and npm without typing -g flag in the command

I ran these commands

```
cd /projects/basics
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

When I moved to the root folder using the `cd` command and checked `npm --version` and `node --version` it shows the corresponding versions.

So what's the need of the `-g` flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

are for installing `npm`, and `nodejs` globally in your Ubuntu, but the `-g` flag is for installing `npm` packages globally for your development. That has nothing to do with `apt-get` command. To install an `npm` package to only a specific development folder you leave out the `-g` flag and that means you can only use that package in that dev folder.